# Cubic Diophantine equations

Tags: diophantine-equations, cubics

We know how to solve Diophantine equations of first degree (linear) and of the second degree. What is available for solving Diophantine equations of the third degree? Let us say that we are given a two-variable polynomial equation P(x,y)=0 with integer coefficients, of third degree in both variables. What known methods or theories are used to solve such a general Diophantine equation of third degree?
Added: I am assuming the polynomial is genuine third degree (i.e. is irreducible) and that all powers of x and y may be present (alas second powers may be always eliminated by appropriate substitutions).

Comment: Personally, I would attack $~x^3 \pm y^3 = k \in \mathbb{Z^+}~$ in two ways [1] Attempt to manually consider $~x^3, y^3,~$ and $~k ~ \pmod{n}$ for various small positive integers $n$ [2] Attempt to examine the factors of $(x^3 \pm y^3)$ and see where this leads.  I might, instead, consider $k_1 + k_2 = k$, and attempt to choose $k_1, k_2$ opportunely, and then try to  examine (for example) the factors of $(x^3 + k_1)$.

Comment: user2661923  Yes, I do similar things, but this is not too general... Note that I mean a general cubic, I do not assume that only third powers are involved, but the first two (second powers can be eliminated by standard substitutions)

Comment: The more variables there can be , the easier it is to solve the equation.

Comment: individ, that is generally true more often than not, but here I am doing only 2 variables. Of course 1 variable would disprove your claim.

Comment: Even a measly equation such as $x^3+y^3=10^{3\times 10^{10000000}}$ will be a major obstacle.

Answer (score 5):

I'll assume $P(x,y)$ is irreducible over the rationals.  The first thing you'll want to look at is its genus.  In many cases the genus will be $1$, meaning this is an elliptic curve.  Especially if it is Weierstrass form, there are ways to find the integer solutions (e.g. with Sage). If it isn't in Weierstrass form, you can put it in Weierstrass form with a rational transformation, look at the rational points of that transformed curve, and try to see which correspond to integer solutions of the original.

Comment: Robert Israel, I am voting this up, since we do not have any other answer. Would Sage find the most general (all) solutions?

Comment: An elliptic curve has only finitely many integer points, and (if it is in Weierstrass form) Sage should find them all.

Comment: And what if  genus is not 1?

Comment: If the genus is $0$, the next step might be to find a parametrization.by rational functions of a single variable.